# Dynamic child pipelines and stop action not working

Tags: gitlab-ci

after adding dynamic child pipelines to our CI pipeline on stop action(eg. deleting branch), stopped working.
In stop job we are deleting created k8s resources, so its important to be executed.
What i noticed is that defining environment in child pipeline is probable cause(without environment section, on stop action is working).

Any ideas?

gitlab-ci.yaml looks like this

```
stages:
  ....
  - deploy
  - tests_prepare
  - maintenance_tests
  ....


deploy_branch_to_k8s:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  dependencies:
    - build_api
  environment:
    name: branches/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    on_stop: stop_deployed_branch_in_k8s
  script:
    - deploy to k8s

stop_deployed_branch_in_k8s:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  when: manual
  dependencies: []
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  environment:
    name: branches/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  script:
    - delete k8s resources

generate_config_tests:
  stage: tests_prepare
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  dependencies:
    - build_api
    ....
  script:
    - python3 ./utils/generate-jobs-config.py > generated-config.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-config.yml  

create_maintenance_tests_pipeline:
  stage: maintenance_tests
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include:
      - artifact: generated-config.yml
        job: generate_config_tests
  variables:
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

generated-config.yml looks something like this

```
stages:
  - tests

run_maintenance_test_job___TEST_NAME__:
  stage: tests
  retry: 2
  environment:
    name: branches/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  needs:
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: generate_config_maintenance_tests
  script:
    - deploy a run tests in k8s
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you should skip the `needs` part altogether in the child pipeline, since it is only used for jobs in the same pipeline. Its upstream will be the parent pipeline anyway.

Comment: Forget to mention that i need artifacts from parent pipeline thus needing ```needs``` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needspipelinejob

Comment: Solved, environment name in child pipelines were overwriting environment in parent pipeline.